# How to load a pdf from the url in IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an application in which i am loading a pdf from the bundle by using

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("hhhh.pdf"), NULL, NULL);.
```

Now i want to load it from my web server. I was done it with a string url  using

```
NSString *strUlr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/hgjgj.pdf"];

CFStringRef aCFString = (CFStringRef)strUlr;

//CFURLRef pdfURL = aCFString;
// NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);

CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(),aCFString, NULL, NULL);
pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
   NSLog(@"%@",pdf);
//CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

but with no success..Can anybody knows how to make this code working.I dont need to load it in to pdf because of some reasons.Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you please see this question [Questin link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347887/how-to-load-a-pdf-from-the-url-in-iphone

Comment: i have this problem and so please help me you have done this

Comment: Hi @hacker can you please help I have the same problem and i already post question and i have done all that which is in your answer but i can't understand how to use pdf document object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still try to get url to resource that is supposed to be in your application bundle, not on remote server. Correct method to create url will be CFURLCreateWithString:

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL, aCFString, NULL);
```

Keep in mind that it may be better to download your pdf and cache it locally before display - that approach will also give you more flexibility in error handling and probable authentication challenges for your url

Comment: Hi @Vladimir can you explain how it works because i have done the above code and in above comment i have already post my question so can you please see my question and what is lack please explain

Comment: please help me i have spent very much time in this but no success please help me! @Vladimir

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA, what exactly you do not understand?

Comment: Here is my Code.. [Link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948021/read-load-pdf-from-server-using-vfrreader

Comment: thanks for replay me i Hope my question link helps to understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

For reading purpose only you can load pdf file in Uiwebview by url.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken then you probably want to read pdf from web server in your iPhone, if so then you can have UIWebView for your requirements: Here's how you can read and store it locally :

First create UIWebView and include <<**UIWebViewDelegate**>>

```
  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourPDF.pdf"]; 
 if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
           // download file , here "https://s3.amazonaws.com/hgjgj.pdf" = pdf downloading link
         NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/hgjgj.pdf"]];
            //Store the downloaded file  in documents directory as a NSData format
         [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [yourWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     [yourWebView setDelegate:self];
     yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
     [yourWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```